# How to zip a single file with Archiver

Tags: node.js

I am trying to zip a single file using the Archiver npm package located: https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver

I have been able to use the following to zip a directory:

```
archive.directory(folderName, false);
```

But when I try to use either of these nothing seems to happen (ie: no zip is generated, file never finishes zipping):

```
archive.file(folderName, { name: 'file4.txt' });
archive.file(fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(file)), {name: 'File' + singleFileCheck});
```

Has anyone run into this issue before? Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance!

edit:

```
module.exports = async function zipper(user, pass, orgid, s4url, apiToken, newOrgName, file) {
  const s4 = require('../testcli/s4');
  const fs = require('fs');
  const archiver = require('archiver');
  const path = require('path');
  var parentDirect;
  if(file == "./"){
    parentDirect = "..";
  }else{
    parentDirect = path.basename(path.dirname(file));
  }
  const newZipFile = parentDirect + '/s4.zip';
  var folderName = file;
  //Checks for existence of infinite loop
  if(path.resolve(parentDirect).length > path.resolve(folderName).length){
    console.log(folderName.search(parentDirect));
    console.error('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'ERROR!!!! : Please adjust where your console is pointed, this will result in an infinite loop. Exiting.');
    return;
  }
  var P = ['\\', '|', '/', '-'];
  var x = 0;

  var output = fs.createWriteStream(newZipFile);
  var archive = archiver('zip');

  scansdisplayinterval = setInterval(function () {
    twrl();
  }, 250);

  // listen for all archive data to be written
  output.on('close', function () {
    console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
    console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
    try {
      process.stdout.write(newZipFile);
      clearInterval(scansdisplayinterval);
      s4(user, pass, newZipFile, orgid, s4url, apiToken, newOrgName);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });

  // good practice to catch this error explicitly
  archive.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
  });

  // good practice to catch warnings (ie stat failures and other non-blocking errors)
  archive.on('warning', function(err) {
    throw err;
  });

  // This event is fired when the data source is drained no matter what was the data source.
  output.on('end', function() {
    console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'Data has been drained');
  });
  
  // pipe archive data to the file
  archive.pipe(output);

  //Checks -f for file extension
  let singleFileCheck = path.extname(file);
  
  //If file has extension
  if(singleFileCheck.length <= 4 && singleFileCheck != ''){
    //Append single file
    console.log('singleFile', path.resolve(file));
    archive.file(path.resolve(file), { name: 'file4.txt' });
    // archive.append(fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(file)), {name: 'File' + singleFileCheck});
  //Else = folder 
  }else{
    // append files from a sub-directory, putting its contents at the root of archive
    archive.directory(folderName, false);
  }
  // archive.directory(folderName, false);

  console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', "Zipping: " + folderName + " To: " + newZipFile);
  console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', "Zipping To: " + path.resolve(newZipFile));

  archive.finalize();
  

  function twrl() {
    process.stdout.write('\rZipping Folder ... ' + P[x++]);
    x &= 3;
  }
  
  return(newZipFile);
};
```

Comment: Looking at the API docs over on the link you specified, you first create a file that you'll be streaming archive data to, and then there are several examples for handling files from file, string, and buffer, with the example code looking rather different from what you're showing. So: try copying the example code, and adapting it to your need first?

Comment: can you show all your code regarding `archive`? We need to see whether you pipe the output, call finalize, etc.

Comment: The 1st parameter to [archive.file()](https://www.archiverjs.com/docs/archiver#file) seems to be a file path, not folder name.

Comment: Ive updated with the rest of the code. The var "foldername" is an absolute path to a file

Comment: Then it's a really poor variable name.

Comment: Thanks :D

It can be a folderName. But in this update, it has the opportunity to be a singular file. Ill update that though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from how I was defining the parentDirect var.

Solution:

```
let singleFileCheck = path.extname(file);
if(file == "./" || singleFileCheck.length <= 4 && singleFileCheck != ''){
    parentDirect = "..";
  }else{
    parentDirect = path.basename(path.dirname(file));
  }
```